# how to find an infinity limit in a fraction

Tags: limits, exponential-function, infinity

I don't understand how to find the limits of this expression when $x\to\infty$ and $x\to-\infty$:

$$\left(\frac{3e^{2x}+8e^x-3}{1+e^x}\right)$$

I've searched for hours. How to compute these limits?

Comment: For $x$ large $3e^{2x}$ and $e^x$ dominate but $e^{2x}\gg e^x$ so this goes to infinity.

Comment: the limit is plus infinity

Comment: Do some long division. The fraction is top heavy.

Comment: i'm sorry, i meant also when x-->-$\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because trying to directly evaluate the limit as $x\to\infty$ gives you the indeterminate form
$$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$
use [L'Hopital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to do
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{3e^{2x}+8e^x-3}{1+e^x}&=
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}(3e^{2x}+8e^x-3)}{\frac{d}{dx}(1+e^x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{6e^{2x}+8e^x}{e^x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}6e^x+8 = \infty
\end{align}

The limit as $x\to-\infty$ can be evaluated directly and is
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{3e^{2x}+8e^x-3}{1+e^x} = \frac{0+0-3}{1+0}=-3$$

Answer (score 2):

First, let's let $u = e^{x}$.  I'm just calling the function $e^{x}$ a different name: $u$.

Now, as $x \to \infty$, we know $e^{x}$ goes to $\infty$, right?  This should be clear if you look at the graph of $e^{x}$.

So, by renaming $e^{x}$ as $u$, we can rewrite the problem as:

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{3(e^{x})^{2} + 8e^{x} - 3}{1 + e^{x}} = \lim \limits_{u \to \infty} \dfrac{3u^{2} + 8u - 3}{1 + u}$.

But

$\lim \limits_{u \to \infty} \dfrac{3u^{2} + 8u - 3}{1 + u} = \lim \limits_{u \to \infty} \dfrac{(3u^{2} + 8u - 3)\cdot \dfrac{1}{u^{2}}}{(1 + u)\cdot \dfrac{1}{u^{2}}} = \lim \limits_{u \to \infty} \dfrac{3 + \dfrac{8}{u} - \dfrac{3}{u^{2}}}{\dfrac{1}{u^{2}} + \dfrac{1}{u}}$.

Now, the numerator goes to the value $3$, while the denominator goes to the value $0$, so the fraction goes to the value $\infty$.  Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for help, i edited the question, i also need x-->-$\infty$

Comment: @tanto30 Well, as $x \to -\infty$, $e^{x} \to 0$, right? So if we use the same trick again where we call $e^{x}$ a new name $u$, then as $x \to -\infty$, $u \to 0$, right?  Now rewrite the limit as:  $\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} \dfrac{3(e^{x})^{2} + 8e^{x} - 3}{1 + e^{x}} = \lim \limits_{u \to 0} \dfrac{3u^{2} + 8u - 3}{1 + u}$.  Can you tell what this limit is now?

Answer (score 1):

By dividing both numerator and denominator  by $ e^{x} $ we get:

$$ \displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{3e^{x}+8-\frac{3}{e^{x}}}{\frac{1}{ e^{x} }+1}$$

Substituting with $\infty$ in the previous equation we get:
$$\frac {\infty +8+0}{0+1} =\infty $$

So it approach $\infty$ as $ x $ goes to $\infty $

Answer (score 0):

To give a complete answer of what everybody is telling you, note we can divide top and bottom by $e^x$ to get

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3e^{2x}+8e^x-3}{1+e^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3e^x+8-3e^{-x}}{e^{-x}+1}=\frac{\infty+8-0}{0+1}=\infty$$

Note the second to last term isn't rigorous because I can't just use infinity like a number, but that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

$3\mathrm e^{2x}+8\mathrm e^x-3\sim_{+\infty}3\mathrm e^{2x}$, $\;1+\mathrm e^x\sim_{+\infty}\mathrm e^x$, hence
$$\frac{3e^{2x}+8e^x-3}{1+e^x}\sim_{+\infty}\frac{3\mathrm e^{2x}}{\mathrm e^x}=3\mathrm e^x \xrightarrow[x\to+\infty]{}+\infty$$
When $x\to-\infty$, as $\mathrm e^x \to 0$, this is no indeterminate form.

Comment: according to wolframalpha, the limit when x --> -$\infty$ is -3... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-3%2B8+e%5Ex%2B3+e%5E%282+x%29%29%2F%281%2Be%5Ex%29

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3e^{2x}+8e^x-3}{1+e^x}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-3e^{-x}+8+3e^x}{1+e^{-x}}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(8+3e^x\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}8+\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(3e^x\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}8+3\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}8+3\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}x\right)=$$
$$8+3\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}x\right)=\infty$$

---

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3e^{2x}+8e^x-3}{1+e^x}=$$
$$\frac{\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(3e^{2x}+8e^x-3\right)}{\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(1+e^x\right)}=$$
$$\frac{\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(3e^{2x}+8e^x-3\right)}{\lim_{x\to-\infty}1+\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^x}=$$
$$\frac{\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(3e^{2x}+8e^x-3\right)}{1+\exp\left(\lim_{x\to-\infty}x\right)}=$$
$$\frac{\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(3e^{2x}+8e^x-3\right)}{1}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(3e^{2x}+8e^x-3\right)=$$
$$3\left(\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^{2x}\right)+8\left(\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^x\right)+\lim_{x\to-\infty}(-3)=$$
$$3\exp\left(\lim_{x\to-\infty}2x\right)+8\exp\left(\lim_{x\to-\infty}x\right)-3=$$
$$3\exp\left(2\lim_{x\to-\infty}x\right)+8\exp\left(\lim_{x\to-\infty}x\right)-3=$$
$$3\cdot 0+8\cdot 0-3=-3$$